# Multiplying Dataframes with Different Dimensions Pandas: Same Number of Columns, But Different Number of Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes.

- df1 with a shape of (1, 3),
- df2 with a shape of (10, 3).

df1 looks like this:

```
    col0    col1    col2 
0   0.3     0.14    0.34
```

df2 looks like this:

```
    col0    col1    col2 
0      5    10      15
1     36    30      39
2     42    21      44
3     49    37      34
4     19    14      50
5     28    27      48
6     19    28      45
7      4    7       8
8     31    4       33
9      3    23      43
```

I would like to multiply df2 to df1, using the column axis; i.e col1 of df2 to col1 of df1; col2 of df2 to col2 of df1; and col3 of df2 to col3 of df1.

The result I seek:

```
    col0    col1    col2 
0   1.5      1.4    5.1
1   10.8    4.2     13.26
2   12.6    2.94    14.96
3   14.7    5.18    11.56
4   5.7     1.96    17
5   8.4     3.78    16.32
6   5.7     3.92    15.3
7   1.2     0.98    2.72
8   9.3     0.56    11.22
9   0.9     3.22    14.62
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
columns = df1.columns
product = df2.multiply(df1[columns], axis=columns)
```

It throws a "Length Mismatch Error" error.

What can be done to make it work? I searched through the forums, but I could not find an answer which matches my exact requirements.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave us a couple of example dataframes - `df1 = pd.DataFrame(...` - so we could just copy from your question instead of making us do the work for you.   Please read [mre].

Comment: The dimensions make it impossible to copy and paste it. Without crowding the screen. Maybe I could create a smaller scaled down frame?

Comment: Yes, a minimal *toy/fake* example is acceptable for your mre's as long as they faithfully represent/reproduce the problem. - In this case shapes (1,5) and (3,5) would suffice. ... something like `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((1,5))*2);df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(21*19).reshape(3,5))` is always helpful.

Comment: Okay, I have edited it.

Comment: try : ``df2.mul(df1.to_numpy())``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to ndarrays and multiply - they should broadcast correctly.

```
vals1 = df1.to_numpy()
vals2 = df2.to_numpy()

result = vals1 * vals2
```

Or

```
df2 * df1.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long way of resolving the challenge:

```
columns = df1.columns
index = df2.index
length = len(df2)
df1_array = df1.to_numpy()
df1_tiled = np.tile(df1_array, (length, 1))
df1_tiled_frame = pd.DataFrame(df1_tiled, columns=columns, index=index)
product = df2.multiply(df1_tiled_frame, axis="columns")
```